# Django adding multiple records with the same foreign key in ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-modeladmin

Suppose I have the following two models `task` and `person`. 
Now each `person` can have multiple tasks (one to many relationship).

Now in the admin app for a person I can only add one foreign key per record thus I'll have to create multiple records for a `person` having a different `task` but the same `email` and `name` fields.

Is there anything I can do in `personAdmin` that would allow me to add multiple `foreign keys` for the same person and in the backend it would create multiple records ?

```
class task(models.Model):
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class person(models.Model):
   task  = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   email =models.CharField(max_length=100) 
   name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class personAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      pass
```

Comment: Did you solved this? Because I'm having the same problem here.
Not in admin page, but in normal template.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a third table with both the first two tables as FOREIGN KEY.

So this is what you have currently

```
class ToDo_Task(models.Model):
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
   task  = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   email =models.CharField(max_length=100) 
   name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Adding a third table

```
class person_task(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(ToDo_Task, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

You may add even more fields in the new table.